# Add fancybox lightbox in wordpress theme without using a plugin 

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fancybox, themes

I want my post images to open in a fancybox lightbox. I have two wordpress websites with two different themes. I am using this code for my images in the lightbox

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-25830 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail">
<a title="image-title" href="image-url"><img class="attachment-thumbnail alignleft" title="image-title" src="image-url" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a>
</div>
```

This code works in one theme, but in the other theme it goes to the image's url. I checked my theme files and found that there is no jquery or js file for fancybox. So I am wondering how I can add these files to my theme and what I should change in my CSS file.
Please someone, help me. I am new to coding.

Comment: I have fancybox folder in other theme, it contains some images and jquery.fancybox-1.3.4. can i use them? and if yes, then how? 
plz someone help

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that ur plugin fancybox would definetly require jquery as one of the pre-header load-in in the HTML script for the browser to initialise jquery functionality. You have to either provide the jquery package from a source or use an external CDN (Google, MS, etc).

This can be done by either coding in the HTML jquery CDN code from [HERE](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) OR download/install [WP PLUGINS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-google-libraries-cdn/) which automatically configure to the latest jquery CDN package.

After ensuring that jquery is part of the header code, ur fancy box should work (or give u some indication that its trying to run). Enjoy :)

Comment: I do not want to use any plugin, plz tell me step my step method

Comment: Fancybox will only work if jquery is loaded in the html <head></head> tags.

you gotta copy `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` in between that <head></head> tags. If your using wordpress from wordpress.com free blogs then it might be hard to do so..

Comment: I have copied <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script> in the header of my theme. Now what to do next? and no i am not using wordpress.com free themes

Answer (score 0):

easily use "conditional lightbox" or "nextgen gallery plugin" or many other sidewide lightbox WP plugins, if u use BP consider that there's just a few number of plugins like "fancybox"  4 buddypress (which has no support). In case of enabling wordpress sidewide lightbox without using plugins see this page: http://fearlessflyer.com/2011/04/how-to-add-lightbox-to-wp-without-plugin/